# Finding font-weight value in selenium IDE

Tags: css, dom, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE and need to identify when an item of text has the css 'font-weight:bold' applied to it (with 'verifyAttribute')

Using the following CSS locator:

```
css=body.home.es ul#languages li:nth-child(2) a.selected
```

Selenium can find the item. I now need to dive into the CSS and confirm that font-weight:bold has been applied.  The CSS of the site I am testing is:

```
ul.language li a.selected {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
```

I've drawn a blank; can it be achieved this way, do I need to dive into DOM locators? Or is Java the solution? (which for me isn't that easy)

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 4):

Since it looks like you need the computed style, I think you you need to use javascript.

You can do this with the following step in Selenium IDE:

```
Command: assertEval
Target: var x = window.document.querySelector('body.home.es ul'); window.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue('font-weight');
Value: 700
```

Note that the value of 700 is a font-weight of bold.

This solution was tested in Firefox. If you are using IE, it'll be slightly different - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle).

Comment: Yup, it'll be different, if it works at all.  IE8 doesn't have getComputedStyle(), and IE7 doesn't have querySelector().  But if you're doing recent browsers, you should be OK.