# Get css value by CSS and use in Selenium

Tags: javascript, css, testing, selenium, selenium-ide

I try to get some website attribute (colour of the cell) and compare in Selenium.

When I put this:

```
javascript:window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("simple_cname"),null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

in Chrome Omnibox, I receive correct answer, but when I, by using storeEval or assertEval try to get this value it does not work correctly.
edit:
I put to selenium command like this. I use storeEval and when I echo the value it returns me this command. I use Firefox. I used Chrome just to chech if the command is correct. (it should be "rgb(220, 22, 92)" )
edit2:
Yes, the command is ok, but I have a problem with using it in Selenium-IDE tool. It do not returns the value when I use it with storeEval command. 
log:
[info] script is: var test javascript:window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("simple_cname"),null).getPropertyValue("background-color"); echo test;
[info] Executing: |echo | ${test} | |
[info] echo: var test javascript:window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("simple_cname"),null).getPropertyValue("background-color"); echo test;

---

I put to selenium command like this. I use storeEval and when I echo the value it returns me this command.
I use Firefox. I used Chrome just to chech if the command is correct. (it should be "rgb(220, 22, 92)" )

Comment: Are you sure you didn't leave the `javascript:` part in the testcase? In which browser are you trying to run the code? Selenium IDE is for Firefox only, AFAIK... Is there any kind of error, or does it return empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `javascript:` part and refer to `document` as `window.document`. The command will then look like this:

```
window.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementById('simple_cname'),null).getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

The `javascript:` part is only needed when running the code from your URL bar, it's redundant *anywhere* else. Use the [`Console`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) instead of your Omnibox to run JS commands in Chrome.

The `document` -> `window.document` thing is mentioned in [the docs](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html) under the `storeEval` section.

Also, note that your script will only work in modern browsers, it will fail in IE < 9. If you're okay with it, fine. If not, [Google has the solution](https://www.google.com/search?q=js%20get%20style).

Comment: [info] Executing: |storeEval | <script>window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("simple_cname"),null).getPropertyValue("background-color");</script> | test |
[info] script is: <script>window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("simple_cname"),null).getPropertyValue("background-color");</script>
[info] Executing: |echo | ${test} | |
[info] echo: window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("simple_cname"),null).getPropertyValue("background-color");

Comment: Also, no `<script>` :). Just the code itself. Remember, it's not a real HTML page, it's just used as a markup for the program to run.

Comment: At first I tried without <script>, but then I get error like this: [info] script is: window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("simple_cname"),null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
[error] Threw an exception: Operation is not supported

Comment: Huh. What about `window.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementById("simple_cname"),null).getPropert‌​yValue("background-color");` ?

Comment: [info] script is: window.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementById("simple_cname"),null).ge‌​tPropert‌​yValue("background-color");
[error] Threw an exception: illegal character

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere :)... `window.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementById('simple_cname'),null).ge‌​tPropert‌​yValue('background-color');` ? If yes, then Selenium IDE is dumber than I thought...

Comment: Worked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699039/how-to-convert-color-from-rrr-ggg-bbb-to-rrggbb-by-javascript) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215963/finding-font-weight-value-in-selenium-ide). Try to find differences, or look somewhere else...

Comment: Your js code was good, I rewrited it in Selenium instead of copying and it worked - some encoding problem and one hour of work. Damn. Thanks very much for help!